# Check Input Prior to Executing a "for loop"

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

is there any way to check or test the input from a 'read' against a for 'loop'?

I don't want the case statement to execute there any of the input is incorrect. As of right now it will loop through, outputting the * ) branch multiple times while still executing the correct inputs.

**Example:**

```
echo "Select Your Options (Seperated by spaces): 1 2 3"
read SELECTION
     # Test SELECTION here? Then exit if fail? IE, if a 4 is entered.

for INPUT in $SELECTION; do
    case $INPUT in
                   1 ) echo "you selection option 1"
                       ;;
                   2 ) echo "you selection option 2"
                       ;;
                   3 ) echo "you selection option 3"
                       ;;
                   * ) echo "Check your selection. Anything outside the following will make this fail:  1 2 3 "
                       RETVAL=1
                       exit          
                       ;; 
    esac
done
```

Comment: Depending on your exact use case, you may be interested in the `select` bash construct; it takes care of presenting numeric options for you.

Comment: @dhag - a `ksh` construct.

Comment: @mikeserv `bash` borrowed (I assume) the `select` statement a very long time ago; it's present in `bash` 2.0 at least.

Comment: I'm not sure if a select construct will be good for this script. The script if looking for specific files in  a directory and moving them to other locations.

IE: If I select option 1) the script moves out all files in a directory that start with S_  .

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
rpt=0
until [ 5 -le "$((rpt+=1))" ] && unset rpt
      printf '\nSelect your Options:(1|2|3): ' >&2
      read  SELECTION &&
      case $SELECTION in 
      (*[!123\ ]*|*[123][123]*|'') ! :
      esac
do    : "${rpt?too many loops!}"
      echo >&2 \
      "Check your selection. Anything outside the following will make this fail:  1 2 3 "
done

for INPUT in $SELECTION
do  case $INPUT  in
                 (1) echo "you selection option 1"
                       ;;
                 (2) echo "you selection option 2"
                       ;;
                 (3) echo "you selection option 3"
                       ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Select Your Options (Seperated by spaces): 1 2 3"
read selection

#exit(1) unless every component of $selection is one of 1, 2, or 3

set -f #to supress glob expansion
for input in $selection; do
  case "$input" in 1);; 2);; 3);; *) exit 1;; esac
done

for input in $selection; do
  case "$input" in
    1 ) echo "you selection option 1"
      ;;
    2 ) echo "you selection option 2"
      ;;
    3 ) echo "you selection option 3"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I see what your doing this. They may cleaner option to use but this does work. I'll try it out.