# Shell Script Loop Conditionally

Tags: shell, shell-script

I just create a new shell script and having trouble with small issue. Below is my script :-

```
function mainMenu(){
    while :
    do
    echo -e "\nMain Menu:"
    echo " A. Process Managements Utilities"
    echo " B. Memory Managements Utilities"
    echo " C. Exit"

    read -p "Select :" menuSelect
    echo

    case $menuSelect in

            a|A) processMgmt;;
            b|B) memoryMgmt;;
            c|C) exit 0;;

            *)echo "Invalid Input"
              echo
              ;;
    esac
    done
}
```

When user Enter 'INVALID INPUT', the function will print all `mainMenu()` output :-

```
Main Menu:
 A. Process Managements Utilities
 B. Memory Managements Utilities
 C. Exit

Select :e
Invalid Input

Main Menu:
 A. Process Managements Utilities
 B. Memory Managements Utilities
 C. Exit

 Select :
```

How to print only `select:` if user input is invalid?

```
Select:e
Invalid input
Select:s
Invalid input
```

Comment: [like this?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250024/52934)

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you want to print information about choice A,B etc only first time, **start `while` loop after printing** it:

```
function mainMenu(){

    echo -e "\nMain Menu:"
    echo " A. Process Managements Utilities"
    echo " B. Memory Managements Utilities"
    echo " C. Exit"

while :
    do

    read -p "Select :" menuSelect
    echo

    case $menuSelect in

            a|A) processMgmt;;
            b|B) memoryMgmt;;
            c|C) exit 0;;

            *)echo "Invalid Input"
              echo
              ;;
    esac
    done
}
```

Example output (which is **expected** from question):

```
Main Menu:
 A. Process Managements Utilities
 B. Memory Managements Utilities
 C. Exit
Select :q

Invalid Input

Select :q

Invalid Input
```

---

By means of this, information about choice selection is printed once when function `mainMenu` is called then `while` loop `read` the input and `case` do the job you want. **In case of invalid input**, `while` loop again ask by `read -p "Select"`.

Comment: @mikeserv I think title of question needs clarification/correction. The `case` option `c` is already provided for `exit`!